# Is there alternative for datalist?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-datalist

```css
datalist {
  color: red;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input list="langs">
<datalist id="langs">
  <option value="Javascript">
  <option value="PHP">
  <option value="C#">
  <option value="C++">
  <option value="C">
  <option value="Python">
  <option value="Java">
  <option value="Ruby">
  <option value="Kotlin">
  <option value="Delphi">
  <option value="Go">
  <option value="Perl">
  <option value="ObjectiveC">
</datalist>
```

I want to use **datalist** but list is being too extended with datas , i cant make it short.Because CSS does not affect it.Do you have any alternative advice for datalist? I dont prefer use **select** because i want that users can be enter input and i want to make like search text , datalist is suitable for this.But in select you have to just select option without text.

Comment: use json object which contains your option

Comment: These functionalities are decided by browsers. You do not have control over it. If you need to customize the count, display property etc, you should use custom control. Check out https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/193/top-10-best-autocomplete-jquery-and-javascript-plugins or https://github.com/pawelczak/EasyAutocomplete these are some of the custom autocomplete control for Javascript and jquery.

Comment: Well, CSS-tricks suggests you to use clamp.js - https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js css-tricks - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/

Answer (score 7):

**I was also stucked in styling the datalist and after some research I am here with this code where I applied my custom css to datalist.**

```js
    var count = 1;
    var group = document.getElementById('slg');
    var list_group = group.querySelector('li ul');
    var list_array = group.querySelectorAll('li ul li');
    var search = group.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    
    search.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
      for (var i = 0; i < list_array.length; i++) { matching(list_array[i]) }
      show_list(list_group);
      key_up_down();
    });
    
    search.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      init_list();
      show_list(list_group);
      key_up_down();
    });
    
    search.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) { e.target.value = list_group.querySelector('[data-highlight="true"]').innerHTML }
      hide_list(list_group)
      init_list();
    });
    
    function matching(item) {
      var str = new RegExp(search.value, 'gi');
      if (item.innerHTML.match(str)) { item.dataset.display = 'true'} 
      else { item.dataset.display = 'false'; item.dataset.highlight = 'false'; count = 0 }
    }
    
    function init_list() {
      count = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < list_array.length; i++) { init_item(list_array[i]); list_array[i].addEventListener('click', copy_paste); }
    }
    
    function init_item(item) { item.dataset.display = 'true'; item.dataset.highlight = 'false'; }
    
    function copy_paste() { search.value = this.innerHTML;
      // todo : check match of list text and input value for .current 
      init_list(); hide_list(list_group);
    }
    
    function hide_list(ele) { ele.dataset.toggle = 'false' }
    
    function show_list(ele) { ele.dataset.toggle = 'true' }
    
    function key_up_down() {
      var items = group.querySelectorAll('li[data-display="true"]');
      var last = items[items.length - 1];
      var first = items[0];
    
      search.onkeydown = function (e) {
        
        if (e.keyCode === 38) {
          count--;
          count = count <= 0 ? items.length : count;
          items[count - 1].dataset.highlight = items[count - 1] ? 'true' : 'false';
          if (items[count]) { items[count].dataset.highlight = 'false'; }
          else { first.dataset.highlight = 'false'; }
        } 
        
        if (e.keyCode === 40) {
          items[count].dataset.highlight = items[count] ? 'true' : 'false';
          if (items[count - 1]) { items[count - 1].dataset.highlight = 'false'; }
          else { last.dataset.highlight = 'false'; }
          count++;
          count = count >= items.length ? 0 : count;
        }
      };
    }
    
    group.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event){
      if (event.target != list_group && event.target.parentNode != list_group){ list_group.dataset.toggle = 'false' }
    });
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
    body {padding: 10%;}
    input, li {padding: 0.6rem 1rem; margin: 0;}
    li {position: relative;}
    ul {list-style: none; padding: 0;}
    li li:hover {color: white; background-color: grey;}
    li li.current {color: white;background-color: pink;}
    #universe {width: 240px;}
    .select-list-group, .select-list-group * {width: 100%;}
    .select-list-group .select-list-group__search + .select-list-group__toggle:after {
      content: "v";
      font-family: sans-serif;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0.6rem;
      right: 0.7rem;
      width: 2rem;
      padding: 0.6rem;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .select-list-group .select-list-group__search:focus + .select-list-group__toggle:after {content: "^";}
    .select-list-group [data-toggle=false] {display: none;}
    .select-list-group [data-toggle=true] {display: inherit;box-shadow: 0 3px 7px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);}
    .select-list-group li[data-display=false] {display: none;}
    .select-list-group li[data-display=true] {display: inherit;}
    .select-list-group li[data-highlight=false] {border-left: 5px solid transparent;}
    .select-list-group li[data-highlight=true] {border-left: 5px solid darkslateblue;}
```

```html
<div id="universe">
      <ul class="select-list-group" id="slg">
        <li>
          <input type="text" class="select-list-group__search" placeholder="Choose month or type"/>
          <span class="select-list-group__toggle"> </span>
          <ul class="select-list-group__list" data-toggle="false">
            <li class="select-list-group__list-item" data-display="true" data-highlight="false">January 2021</li>
            <li class="select-list-group__list-item" data-display="true" data-highlight="false">February 2021</li>
            <li class="select-list-group__list-item" data-display="true" data-highlight="false">March 2021</li>
            <li class="select-list-group__list-item" data-display="true" data-highlight="false">April 2021</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```